# Codeception set session variables

Tags: php, codeception

Is there a way to set a session variable with Codeception? I tried:

```
$_SESSION['variable'] = true;
```

But that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sessions with Selenium module in Codeception (because it uses browser's instance to test pages). With PHPBrowser module your sessions will not work by default (because it uses independent CURL requests to get page content). So you can:

a) set session cookie manually:

```
$I->wantTo('test something');
$I->setCookie('sessionid', '123213123123123');
$I->amOnPage('/test');
```

b) create some helper class and store your variables there (I recommend this way).

**tests/_helpers/AppHelper.php:**

```
class AppHelper extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public static $global;
    ...
```

**acceptance test:**

```
AppHelper::$global = 'test';
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error, and, maybe, i found solution.

NOTE: i use Yii2 with PhpBrowser

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace tests\frontend\acceptance;

// use ...

class MyCest
{
  public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
  {
    $_SESSION = [
      // some session values
      'id' => 15
    ];

    session_commit();

    /*
    PHPSESSID - is a default name
    but in Yii2 config you may override it
    check 'session' component in config
    */
    $I->setCookie('PHPSESSID', session_id(), [
      'domain' => ''
    ]);

    $I->amOnPage('/page');
  }
}
```

And in PageController i **check exist** session variable
And it **exist**!

P.S. **sorry for my bad english**